# Setup for HTML to PDF on server

Tags: pdf, laravel, snappy

Im using Laravel and am trying to use a package for easy HTML to PDF conversion. The one I'm currently trying is 'snappy':

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy

Am I missing a step for configuring locally in MAMP? When I followed the instructions to include snappy in composer.json and installing its all good, but when I try to use the pdf functions, it throws a variety of errors that I can't sort out.

I'm reading about needing wkhtmltopdf, but am getting confused on how to do actually do that and can't find any straightforward articles.

Can anyone provide any guidance here?

Comment: Similar errors here:https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/10 like I said, I'm not tracking on getting getting wkhtmltopdf installed...

Comment: Looks like a permissions error in that thread. Try changing the folder permissions in the folder you're writing to to be rwxrwxrwx (chmod 777) to see if that works?

Comment: Did you try to generate via cmd line? How did you build wkhtmltopdf also?

Comment: I just included it via composer and ran 'composer install'. I'm getting this error:
The exit status code '126' says something went wrong:
stderr: "sh: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site.com/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64: cannot execute binary file

Comment: What do I need to do to make the binary file executable? and why isn't it executable by default?

Answer (score -1):

I used snappy pdf with my php project and wrote a blog.You can try this.It will work any php projects http://www.kingpabel.com/php-html-to-pdf-snappy/